# LakeFormation does not support accessing data for partitions with location that is not sub-path of table location

Tags: aws-lake-formation

I am querying a glue table shared using lake formation and getting this error.

```
HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: com.amazonaws.services.lakeformation.model.AWSLakeFormationException: Error retrieving data access credentials for (table: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:table/yyyyyyyy/zzzzzzz, partition: {Values: [1, 1598859287382, 1598859287382, SNAPSHOT]}). LakeFormation does not support accessing data for partitions with location that is not sub-path of table location. (Service: null; Status Code: 403; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you added a partition manually, that is not under the location set in the parent table. You can read more on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/limitations.html#issue-table-partitions).